# Javascript function argument evaluation

Tags: javascript, function

I have a custom function, let's call it `func`.

```
function func(someArg) {
    return Math.random() + someArg;
}
```

I have an array of `Thing` objects and these objects all have some kind of functionality `exec`

```
var Thing = function() {
    this.exec = function(n) {
        console.log(n);   
    }
}

var arr = [new Thing(), new Thing(), new Thing()];
```

Now, I want to be able to execute a function for all elements in the array, and the argument of that function should be evaluated for every function execution. An example:

```
function execAll(arg) {
    arr.forEach(function(e) { e.exec(arg); });
}

execAll(func(10));
```

This returns 3 times the same value, because `func()` is evaluated once for the call of `execAll` and then used in every `e.exec(arg)`. How can I achieve that `func` is evaluated for every invokation of `e.exec`?

**UPDATE**

It would be very nice if there was a solution that supported using both:

```
execAll(someFunc()); // invoked with a function
execAll(20); // invoked with a plain value
```

Whole snippet here:

```js
var Thing = function() {
    this.exec = function(n) {
        console.log(n);   
    }
}

var arr = [new Thing(), new Thing(), new Thing()];

var func = function(someArg) {
    return Math.random() + someArg;
}

function execAll(arg) {
    arr.forEach(function(e) { e.exec(arg); });
}

execAll(func(10));
```

Comment: Bad idea. Use two different `exec` methods to do different things.

Comment: Yes you are right. I should reconsider my whole design for this. However, I accepted Royi's answer, as it solves the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this :

```
function execAll(arg) {
    arr.forEach(function(e) { e.exec(arg); });
}

execAll(function (){func(10)});
```

with this :

```
    function execAll(arg) {
      arr.forEach(function(e) { e.exec(typeof arg==='function'?arg():arg); });
    }

  execAll( 10);
```

You should send a function to be future invoked for each iteration.

What you're actually doing is invoking it immediately.

Comment: I can't see where I used `execAll(function (){func(10)});`. Did you mean `execAll(func(10));`? Anyways, I understand your solution. It works if the argument of `execAll()` is always a function. But is there a way to include constructs like `execAll(17)` as well? With your solution it would fail because `17()` can't be executed. Do I have to check if the argument is a function, or is there another solution?

Comment: Thats a cleaner solution, I thought about that myself, inspired by your answer. But it has the same problem when trying to call `execAll` with a plain value like `17`. It gives `Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function`. I described it above. Do I **have** to check if the argument is a function and if so, call it?

Comment: @Jeyp yes . JS has to know what it is going to deal with. you have to check if its function or scalar etc.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the most recent version?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the function func a private function of Thing. This provides encapsulation..

```
var Thing = function() {
    var func = function(someArg) {
        return Math.random() + someArg;
    };
    this.exec = function(n) {
        console.log(func(n));   
    };
}

var arr = [new Thing(), new Thing(), new Thing()];

function execAll(arg) {
    arr.forEach(function(e) { e.exec(arg); });
}

execAll(10);
```

Comment: Good point, but my construction is actually an abstraction of a problem where I cant use your refactoring.